# Adding a SQL Default value of 01 to a database column

Tags: sql, sql-server, types

How do you add the following default value to a sql database table?

```
01
```

I have tried various datatypes but the 0 keeps disappearing.  I haven't even been able to find an example on the exchange or google but I assume this is very straight forward and I am being a numpty!!!

I have tried numeric/integer/varchar without luck.  Thanks.

Comment: What is the data type of the column you are trying to default?

Comment: Show as the DDL for that column

Comment: I used the answer below - the problem was related to SSMS and the existing table design I guess.  I couldn't alter it correctly no matter what I tried - Simply recreating the tables did the trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
create table MyTable (Id int, Value varchar(100) not null default('01'))
Insert into MyTable (Id) values (1) 

Select Value
From MyTable 

will be '01'
```

[Sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4048d/1)

Comment: I had to drop 4 tables, I can't explain why but I was trying to add the default values via alter table commands and the SSMS but it just wouldn't stick - doing the above but via SSMS gave me 1.00 on a varchar column...anyway after recreating the tables and re-populating it has worked fine.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be:

Open your Table Designer and you will see something like this:

[image]

If you prefer code:

```
USE ["name of your dataBase"] 
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_1](
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[sample02] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[sample03] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Table_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,      ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]  ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table_1] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Table_1_sample02]  DEFAULT ('01') FOR [sample02]
GO
```

---

And finally, you can visit this Microsoft post: [Specify Default Values for Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187872.aspx)

Comment: I am afraid I tried both of those, the designer looked exactly as your does but whenever I reviewed the content it stated either "1" or "1.00"...No idea why.  Running alter table commands didn't work.  I think there was a more unusual underlying problem as nothing worked until I simply dropped and recreated the table.

Comment: Very strange. I have updated the code a little bit. May be a clause missed. Using the designer must work fine, IDK.